# cross site request forgery - in .net using web forms in vs2013

Tags: asp.net

With the auto generated code for VS 2013 for web forms, it adds CSRF protection. Do I need to do anything else to get it to work?

It says the token is added to Page.ViewStateUserKey.  How am I suppose to check the ViewState? The debugger says it's null.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication12
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
        private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
        private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
            var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
            Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
            if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
            {
                // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

                var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
                };
                if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
                {
                    responseCookie.Secure = true;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
            }

            Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
        }

        protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Set Anti-XSRF token
                ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
                ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
                if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                    || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Asp.net ViewState Helper. And because I was using 4.5 framework uses a different cyprtoscheme, I had to edit the web.config.

I added this:

```
  <system.web>
    <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" />
  </system.web>
```

Then I was able use Fiddler and decrypt the View State and confirmed that the XSRF token is added.